# Django rest framework: not updating the results immediately

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 2.0 and Django rest framework 3.7.3. I have updated the published_date field of an object but when i retrieve the list of posts it does not reflect. I think its showing the old results

```
postsclass PostListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    today = timezone.now()
    def get_queryset(self):
        today = timezone.now()
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        return articles.filter(publish_date__lte=today).order_by('-publish_date')[:30]

    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    publish_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC")

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = "__all__"
```

what to do so that the changes are reflected immediately in the api

Comment: Can you add code which updating date field?

Comment: I have a simple model and changing the publish_date from admin page

Comment: No reason it doesn't unless the code you pasted has been striped too much and that the culprit was removed in the process.

Comment: i found that it can be due to gunicorn and nginx. Because  it doesnot cache when i run locally. But when i put on server its caching